# Can't query instagram user with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api, facebook-business-sdk

Things were working find until yesterday. I'm developing a simple Instagram app, I made a basic login flow. Now, when I try to log in for the app with a business facebook account I get a message `"You don't have any Instagram Business Accounts linked to a Page."`, which is funny, because in business account manager, in "Instagram Accounts" tab, I have my business instagram account listed; trying to remove it gives me a message: `"This Instagram Account can't be removed because it's already linked to an Instagram business profile."`. Great, seems like it SHOULD be working. It isn't but, the second part follows.

I generated an access token for that instagram account for Instagram Basic Display API, queried node `https://graph.instagram.com/me`, I got my account ID in response. Now, I tried to query the user using Graph API - `https://graph.facebook.com/17841431928202825` - but in response I get:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '17841431928202825' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "AwbBT4_pYZjEg5HbG1UHYPi"
   }
}
```

For this I'm using an access token generated for the facebook account.
Do you have any idea why the hell it can't see my account both querying the API and from Business manager?

Comment: I don’t get what you are trying to do here. The ID you got from `graph.instagram.com/me`, is an IG user ID - good for making requests with the Basic Display API. What makes you think that same ID could be used for requests against `graph.facebook.com`?

Comment: The Instagram Graph API uses the same API hostname as the normal FB Graph API, `graph.facebook.com`. But the Instagram Basic Display API is not the same thing as the Instagram Graph API.

Comment: @CBroe I know, but later I'm trying to query `https://graph.facebook.com/ig_hashtag_search` which requires user_id that is a valid ID of a business instagram account. When I'm trying to use it, I get an error message of `"(#100) Param user_id is not a valid Instagram User ID"` - while it worked just yesterday.